# plugin simple auctions woocommerce doesn't display correctly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed simple auctions plugin for woocommerce on martfury theme (https://themeforest.net/item/martfury-woocommerce-marketplace-wordpress-theme/21273233)
but I can not see the "bid now" button on the single product page. I have contacted the support of the theme and they said that they did not test the plugin with the theme.
Is there any solution ?

This is what I want : https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/06/0zg5.png

This is what I am getting : https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/06/vb2b.png

Comment: ¿Do you have any URL where we can see some code? Without that is going to be really difficult to help. Also, it's better the Theme devs take care of that issue, because they know better the code of the theme. Do you know if they are doing a follow up on that issue?

Comment: thank you, i m working in local so i can't send u an url sorry, the developers just say that they didn't test the plugin with the theme

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce -> Settings -> Auctions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPmfw.jpg)

(uncheck this options)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).